# Error in Vim: "YouCompleteMe unavailable: This package should not be accessible on Python 3"

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, virtualenv, youcompleteme

When I attempt to use the YouCompleteMe plugin in vim, I get the following error:

`YouCompleteMe unavailable: This package should not be accessible on Python 3.  Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted`

However, I only get this error when I open vim within my virtual environment. It works fine when a virtualenv is not active. My guess is that YouCompleteMe is written in python 2, and for some reason can't see the python2 interpreter from inside the virtual environment, but I am not sure how to fix it. There does not appear to be a Stack Overflow question on the subject, but a similar issue came up in the ycm-users Google Group and went unanswered.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, using vim version 7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug:

https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/pull/578

> In PR #448, I made the assumption that the site-packages paths are always placed after the standard library path so that if we insert the python-future module just before the first site-packages path, it would necessary be after the standard library. Turns out that it is not true when a site-packages path is added to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, e.g, when using the software ROS. See issue Valloric/YouCompleteMe#2186. When this happens, the python-future module will raise the following exception on Python 3:
>
> ```
>  ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3.
>  Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or
>  your installation of python-future is corrupted.
> ```
>
> We prevent this by looking for the standard library path in sys.path and by inserting the python-future module just after it. If we can't find it, we raise an exception since YCM and ycmd cannot work without it.
>
> Fixes [Valloric/YouCompleteMe#2186](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2186)

With the above pull request merged, you should be able to fix the issue by pulling the updates--or cloning the repo if haven't already--and reinstalling.

Comment: Ah, I looked at that issue a few days ago, but it looks like there was a commit w/in the last day that fixed the issue. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are using using python 3 inside virtualenv. As far as vim is concerned, you are running python 3 which is not supported by ycm

https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1140

A workaround would be to just open vim from outside your virtualenv

Comment: I came across that same github issue. However, that is from 2014, and it appears from YouCompleteMe's [readme](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) that it currently supports Python 3.

I'm not sure it's a problem with YouCompleteMe itself, since it's tied to the use of virtualenv. I could open vim outside the virtulenv, but then YouCompleteMe can't see any of the libraries I'm using, which defeats the purpose. I guess I could see if I can disable YCM in python files and use jedi-vim instead.